# Vuetify data-table row does not expand

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I'm building a vuetify `<v-data-table>` with button icons on the right-most column. The button icons appear when a data row is hovered. I'd like the data row to expand when the row is clicked, but it's not working.

**Current codepen implementation [here](https://codepen.io/idotuchman/pen/QWyaaMz?editors=1011)**

The code creates a `<v-data-table>` as follows:

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      item-key="name"
      class="elevation-1"
      :items-per-page="5"
      :expanded.sync="expanded"
>
```

And this is the slot to expand the row:

```
<template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
        <td :colspan="headers.length">More info about {{ item.name }}</td>
</template>
```

I'm hoping someone with vuetify experience can help me get the data table rows to expand when clicked. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. [Here](https://codepen.io/idotuchman/pen/YzwYBze) is the updated data table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your code like this:

```html
 <template v-slot:item="{index, item, isExpanded, expand}">
            <tr 
               @mouseover="toolsIndex=index" 
               @mouseleave="toolsIndex=null" 
               @click="expand(!isExpanded)"
            >
              <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.calories }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.fat }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.carbs }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.protein }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.iron }}</td>
              .....
```

Comment: How can I make without `template v-slot:item`? Use only `v-data-table` or with `template v-slot:expanded-item`.

Comment: You can make it without `template v-slot:item` and use only `template v-slot:expanded-item` - take a look at the example in the documentation (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#expandable-rows)

Comment: without `v-slot:item`?

Comment: Do you see a `v-slot:item` anywhere in the example in Vuetify documentation ?

Answer (score 2):

hey because you want to expand your row maybe you can try the vuetify expansionpanel?

it cloud look something like this

```
<template v-slot:item="{index, item}">           
   <v-expansion-panels>
    <v-expansion-panel>
     <v-expansion-panel-header>{{ item.name }}</v-expansion-panel-header>
      <v-expansion-panel-content>
       <v-simple-table>
        <template v-slot:default>
         <thead>
          <tr>
           <td>Calories</td>
           <td>Fat (g)</td>
           <td>Carbs (g)</td>
           <td>Protein (g)</td>
           <td>Iron (%)</td>
           </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
           <tr @mouseover="toolsIndex=index" @mouseleave="toolsIndex=null">
            <td @click="expandRow(index)">{{ item.calories }}</td>
            <td @click="expandRow(index)">{{ item.fat }}</td>
            <td @click="expandRow(index)">{{ item.carbs }}</td>
            <td @click="expandRow(index)">{{ item.protein }}</td>
            <td @click="expandRow(index)">{{ item.iron }}</td>
            <td>
             <v-icon
                  v-show="index==toolsIndex"
                  small
                  class="mr-2"
                  @click.stop="dialog = true"
                  >mdi-pencil</v-icon
                >
                <v-icon
                  v-show="index==toolsIndex"
                  small
                  @click.stop="dialog = true"
                  >mdi-delete</v-icon
                >
             </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
         </template>
        </v-simple-table>
       </template>
      </v-data-table>
     </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-expansion-panels>         
          </template>
```

Comment: Great suggestion. I'll check out expansion panels.

Comment: How can I make without `template v-slot:item`? Use only `v-data-table` or with `template v-slot:expanded-item`.

Answer (score 1):

just change your code block like below, problem solved [here](https://codepen.io/mahamudul-hasan-the-looper/pen/XWXVYYe?editors=1011)

```
<template v-slot:item="{index, item, isExpanded, expand}">
            <tr @mouseover="toolsIndex=index" 
                @click="expand(!isExpanded)"
                @mouseleave="toolsIndex=null">
              <td @click="expandRow(index)">{{ item.name }}</td>
              <td @click="expandRow(index)">{{ item.calories }}</td>
              <td @click="expandRow(index)">{{ item.fat }}</td>
              <td @click="expandRow(index)">{{ item.carbs }}</td>
              <td @click="expandRow(index)">{{ item.protein }}</td>
              <td @click="expandRow(index)">{{ item.iron }}</td>
              <td>
                <v-icon
                  v-show="index==toolsIndex"
                  small
                  class="mr-2"
                  @click.stop="dialog = true"
                  >mdi-pencil</v-icon
                >
                <v-icon
                  v-show="index==toolsIndex"
                  small
                  @click.stop="dialog = true"
                  >mdi-delete</v-icon
                >
              </td>
            </tr>
          </template>
```

Comment: Thank you Md. This is very helpful.

Comment: How can I make without `template v-slot:item`? Use only `v-data-table` or with `template v-slot:expanded-item`.